# Why doesn't invoke the function comes from the same so?

Tags: android-ndk

I hit an interesting problem when I try something on android. I define a function named `pthread_mutex_lock` in `libx.so`, add write a test application which is linked with both `libx.so` and `libc.so` in order:

```
arm-linux-androideabi-readelf -d ./libx-test.out:

Dynamic section at offset 0xebc contains 29 entries:
Tag        Type                         Name/Value
...
0x00000001 (NEEDED)                     Shared library: [libx.so]
0x00000001 (NEEDED)                     Shared library: [libc.so]
...
```

You can see, this test application is linked with both `libx.so` and `libc.so`. `libx.so` is linked before `libc.so`.

Now, I run the test application, from the debugger, I notice this call stack:

```
Breakpoint 1, 0xf7741364 in pthread_mutex_lock () from 
target:/data/local/tmp/libx.so
(gdb) bt
#0  0xf7741364 in pthread_mutex_lock () from target:/data/local/tmp/libx.so
#1  0xf76f5660 in __pthread_internal_add(pthread_internal_t*) () from 
    target:/system/lib/libc.so
...
```

The interesting thing is that `pthread_mutex_lock()` is invoked from a function `__pthread_internal_add()` inside `libc.so`. In `libc.so`, there is a `pthread_mutex_lock()` function existed already:

```
arm-linux-androideabi-nm -g /system/lib/libc.so | grep pthread_mutex_lock
00047a74 T pthread_mutex_lock
...
```

Shouldn't `__pthread_internal_add()` inside `libc.so` invoke the internal function from the same so? Why it invokes the function from another (external) so?

Comment: Isn't this just symbol preemption? That is, your shared object was loaded first, therefore any symbols it exports has priority over symbols with the same names exported by libraries that are loaded later (e.g. `libc.so` in this case).

Comment: I think if one symbol can be found in the same so, the address of that function should be resolved at the time when the linker to generate the so. That symbol won't be marked as undefined. So it shouldn't be resolved at loading time by dynamic library loader. Isn't true?

Comment: That probably would've been true if `pthread_mutex_lock` was given internal or protected visibility in libc, but if it's an exported symbol I think what you're seeing is what you can expect. See e.g. https://holtstrom.com/michael/blog/post/437/Shared-Library-Symbol-Conflicts.html

Comment: Thanks a lot! I get some hints from that blog.

Answer (score 1):

This behavior depends on **-bsymbolic** linker option. This has recently changed in Android NDK: https://github.com/android-ndk/ndk/wiki/Changelog-r16:

> GCC no longer uses -Bsymbolic by default. This allows symbol preemption as specified by the C++ standard and as required by ASAN. For libraries with large numbers of public symbols, this may increase the size of your binaries.